# jQuery [object Object] is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js

I am trying to select tree-node element with children and first child but it is not a valid selector.

```
<g class="nodes">
   <g class="tree-node enter" id="tree-node-cdl3c5he">
      <g class="node-group">
        <circle class="node-shape" r="80"></circle>
        <g class="node-label-group" transform="translate(-80,-80)">
        <foreignObject class="node-content-container" width="160" height="160">
        <div class="node-content">
         <div class="inner">
          <div class="node-label" data-test-id="node-label-new-part">New Part</div>
        </div></div></foreignObject></g><g class="root-group" transform="translate(0,-80)"><circle class="root-shape" r="15"></circle></g>
</g>
</g>
</g>
```

Using first child:

```
$('.nodes > .tree-node:first-child')
```

Ember test:

```
await click($('.nodes > .tree-node:first-child'));
```

Error:
Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#ember-testing [object Object]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: $('.nodes >.tree-node:first-child')

Comment: @waqas Error: [object Object] is not a valid selector.

Comment: What is the specific line of code that throws that error? Because it's not one you've shown here; that selector matches the `g.treenode.enter` node.

Comment: I am using this in Ember testing with click function. `await click($('.nodes > .tree-node :first-child'));` enter and tree-node are two different classes as you may know.

Comment: OK - I'm not familiar with Ember so can't help you there, but the selector you've given here does match that node (with those two separate classes, yes; `g.treenode.enter` is another valid selector for the same node.) You may want to expand on the code you've shown and/or tag the question with Ember, since the issue you're having may be specific to that framework.  (Is it possible you're running this before DOM ready, so that the selector is empty when the script runs?)

Comment: Yes, it runs after the DOM ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By accessing the object like `$('.nodes > .tree-node:first')[0]` worked.

Answer (score 1):

`$('.nodes > .tree-node:first-child')` works fine and is not an invalid selector as seen below. It will return the first child of `.nodes` with the class `.tree-node` , if you however want to fget the first child within `.tree-node` then you need to add a space `$('.nodes > .tree-node :first-child')`

---

> `$('.nodes > .tree-node:first-child')`
>   Expected ► `<g class="tree-node enter" id="tree-node-cdl3c5he">`

```js
var x = $('.nodes > .tree-node:first-child');
console.log(x)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<g class="nodes">
  <g class="tree-node enter" id="tree-node-cdl3c5he">
    <g class="node-group">
      <circle class="node-shape" r="80"></circle>
      <g class="node-label-group" transform="translate(-80,-80)">
        <foreignObject class="node-content-container" width="160" height="160">
          <div class="node-content">
            <div class="inner">
              <div class="node-label" data-test-id="node-label-new-part">New Part</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </foreignObject>
      </g>
      <g class="root-group" transform="translate(0,-80)">
        <circle class="root-shape" r="15"></circle>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
```

---

> `$('.nodes > .tree-node :first-child')`
>   Expected ► `<g class="node-group">`

```js
var x = $('.nodes > .tree-node :first-child');
console.log(x)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<g class="nodes">
  <g class="tree-node enter" id="tree-node-cdl3c5he">
    <g class="node-group">
      <circle class="node-shape" r="80"></circle>
      <g class="node-label-group" transform="translate(-80,-80)">
        <foreignObject class="node-content-container" width="160" height="160">
          <div class="node-content">
            <div class="inner">
              <div class="node-label" data-test-id="node-label-new-part">New Part</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </foreignObject>
      </g>
      <g class="root-group" transform="translate(0,-80)">
        <circle class="root-shape" r="15"></circle>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks!